# How to understand the following shell script?

Tags: shell

I would be glad if somebody could explain me what this part of the code does

```
[ -n "${0%/*}" ] && cd ${0%/*}
. ./environment.sh
. ./readParams.sh
```

I understand that this script is reading from `./enviroment.sh` and `./readparams.sh`

But i am really struggling to understand what the first line of the code does.So i can understand the whole process after this.

I would be glad if you could give me a site or anything that will help me understand such a syntax. I am a beginner in shell script so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget the Python?

Comment: This is not Python code.

Comment: maybe i am mistaken,and is a shell script,but the question remains.If you have any information about where should i look to understand what this syntax does.Sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: It would be better if you could also edit my title so it not confuses the users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a shell script, not python.

```
[ -n "${0%/*}" ] && cd ${0%/*}
```

That changes the current working directory to the directory where the shell script resides.

```
. ./environment.sh
. ./readParams.sh
```

That sources the two listed shell script, presumable stored within the same directory as the script being called.

To break down the first line, `$0` will contain the first argument of the command i.e. the script being called. `${0%/*}` performs a [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to remove the trailing portion (from the last `/` onwards) so this effectively gives you the directory name.

`[ -n "${0%/*}" ]` translates to "if  `"${0%/*}"` results in a string that is not empty".

The whole line therefore translates to "if the executed script is prefixed with a path, then `cd` to that directory".

p.s. I'm not convinced that's the best way to achieve that, but that's pretty much what it does. Personally, I would opt for the more readable `cd $(dirname "$0")`, or for a more robust solution, see [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in).

Comment: Thank you very much!So that is i think the reason that i am reading all day python and i could not find anything that will make me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

first, this is not python at all, even not close!

```
[ -n "${0%/*}" ] && cd ${0%/*}
```

it used parameter expansion, you can man bash to see it.

basically, it `cd` to the directory, which your script is located. for example:

if your script is at:

```
/foo/bar/baz/xxx.sh
```

the above line does `cd /foo/bar/baz`

the files:

```
environment.sh
readParams.sh
```

are in same directory of `xxx.sh`